# How I can monitor traffic on a certain port with munin?

Tags: administration, monitoring, traffic

How I can monitor traffic on a certain port with munin?

I already use plugin port_ to see number of connection on a certain port, but I also need to see the traffic.

Comment: One cool guy told me about plugin called ip_port_ but I have no clue where to get it...

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!